# Documentation: splitting the command line section

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I am asking this here, as suggested in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32377949#32377949)

[command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/command-line) (and the associated tag) is a bit vague and can be misleading.

Should it be Unix or windows-oriented? I think there should be two separate documentation entries to avoid confusion, and clean up the documentation.

The current structure forces us to cover both cases, which complexifies the write up, and might not be useful to users who are looking it up for a specific environment anyway.

What do you think? Any feedback?

Comment: I do not believe you can have documentation about something associated to many independent and, in some cases, totally unrelated bunch of tools. Better is to stick to document tags that are concrete.

Comment: While that's true, I think there is a value writing documentation about a subset of tools (maybe coreutils, for instance; or even Busybox commands). The documentation should in my (very personal) view be a start where beginners can start, and I remember struggling with commands as simple as `pwd` when I was young (by simply forgetting them and not having an easy way to find them back). If more people beleive there should be no such thing as a `command-line` documentation, however, then the section should simply be removed.

Comment: How is coreutils or busybox related to programming in first place? Lets ask the important questions here.

Comment: Here's another vote for only documenting narrower tags (bash, cmd, whatever). We could either not have command-line Docs, or just use them to redirect to the other tags' Docs.

Comment: @Braiam - I though you were speaking about command line itself (that is, treating `ls`, `cat`, `ln`, etc as independent and unrelated tools). But from your answer, I get you were talking about multiple environment/shells/whatever. Somewhat different.