# Add an ability to star documentation entries as favorite

Tags: feature-request, documentation, bookmarks

I am splitting up my [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332756/), [as suggested](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32379238#32379238).

I think it would be great to be able to star documentation entries, as it would allow us to find our way back quickly to non-trivial parts, or ones that are not used often.

As an example, I stumbled on a language feature I didn't know, and I thought "It would be a nice feature to use". Starring the entry would allow me not to forget about it.

Comment: Do people not use bookmarks/favorites any more? I'm genuinely curious. I've got something like 3000 bookmarks in my browser for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Me too, @Mike. The *real* question is, how often do you ever go back and look at them? Do you remember everything you've saved there so you could go back and pull it out, or would you just hop on Google and search for it again (and actually find it more quickly that way)?

Comment: As with a lot of things @CodyGray, some more often than others :). I tend to put reference items in my "bookmark bar" so I can get to them quickly. For instance, MDN Array.prototype.splice is in there because I always get it confused with slice in terms of what arguments it takes. But that one website? Where I saw a cool watch? Nah, haven't opened that since I bookmarked it. :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan so I wasn't the only one? :D