# Please add a way to star a documentation item

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I am used to learning from documentation and sometimes I want to keep a record of it so it would be helpful if I could have a feature of marking documentation for an future reference.

Note: For those who are marking this question duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334513/documentation-mark-as-favorite-button-really-lacks), it has yet not been answered.

Comment: Where is the answer ?

Comment: I really recommend you start learning from somewhere else. Stack Overflow documentation is quickly losing its credibility.

Comment: Can you recommend any please @leaf

Comment: It does not need to be answered here to be a duplicate.  The fact that you are asking the same feature request makes it a duplicate.  We don't need N questions all asking for the same feature.

Comment: But we need an explanation why feature-request is not being answered and by this time I have learned that Comments have no significance on SO or any other SE site

Comment: @IshanMahajan Just look for the official documentation for whatever programming language/tool your trying to learn. Unless of course there is absolutely nothing better than the documentation you find here(which is unlikely).

Comment: It's on the devs list.  Eventually they will get around to giving it an official status.  Some FR's take years to get an official response.

Comment: @leaf I go for W3C and other website but They don't provide as much examples and variety of topics of related topic at one place.

Comment: I can understand but this is the time I'm learning those features added will be of lesser or no use later on in my life. @NathanOliver and more over subsequent feature request might be bringing The feature into account of the Devs

Comment: Isn't this like your browser's bookmarks feature?

Comment: Yup but I have subsequent change in my OS so I can't have bookmarks for a longer period.

Comment: Note that the nominal duplicate is itself a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332764/215552. I had voted to close that and the OP had the same reaction as the OP of this "it's not a duplicate because the other one never got answered and I want an answer". I believe the flag aged away...

Comment: Yo the user of those feature will understand only.I understand documentation is in beta version means still being worked on it might be easier to add the requested features